# Typing a Custom RxJS Operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a custom RxJS operator that `map`s data that comes back from our API. Here's the Operator:

```
export function mapActionResult(): OperatorFunction<ActionResult<any>, any> {
    return map((data: ActionResult<any>) => data.result);
}

// in use:
getData() {
  return this._http.get(this.someUrl).pipe(
    mapActionResult()
  )
}
```

I would like to get the `ActionResult<any>` typed but am not sure how to do that. The `ActionResult` interface takes a generic to type it properly, so I'm hoping to be able to type this operator as well.

Answer (score 2):

A [friend on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Nartc1410) gave me [the following answer](https://twitter.com/Nartc1410/status/1499441280610443275), which is correct and works:

```
export function mapActionResult<T>(): OperatorFunction<ActionResult<T>, T> {
    return map((data: ActionResult<T>) => data.result);
}
```